# Revision id in node table is not found in node_revision table in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I came across a strange problem in drupal. While navigating to the content, I got 404 page. While inspecting the DB, I came to know that the Revision id in Node table is not found in node_revision. Don't know the root cause of this issue.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: are you seeing it ok for other content? See also drupal.stackexchange.com for possible answers.

Comment: Yes. For other content, the revision id seems to be OK. Only for that particular content the revision id is not same.

Since I used view to show a group of content, clicking on the content (with issue) leads to 404 page.

Is there is any filter, so that i can vomit that 404 content in view?

Comment: I haven't seen your problem specifically, that's not to say it hasn't happened for others before. I guess the next thing to try is can you get to your content via another URL? If so, compare this to the one that the View is generating.

Comment: I just modified the revision id in all the associated fields of the particular content and it is working fine.

Is this issue is related to running cron? Don't know the root cause of this issue. please help me.

Comment: Paulraj - glad it's solved for you though I would certainly share your concern perhaps that because you don't know the root cause, you are concerned that the problem may re-arise, I'd be the same. But at the moment your guess is as good as mine. I've not seen this issue before. But there are many issues out there - no one person would have seem them all or have the capacity to do so. I'm not sure if there is a special case where it does happen.

Comment: Another possibility for a root cause reason could be that more than one update to your database took place and left it inconsitent. Though I'd like to think would be more about the setup environment than Drupal itself allowing this to happen as there ought to be safeguards in place. Indeed the database APIs that Drupal uses should provide a means of locking to stop inconsistencies due to simultaneous access.